# Story: world ended because it ran out of jokes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'd like to know who wrote this old short story and its name. I read it 30 years ago or so and I'd love to read that book again.

As far as I can remember, it told how the world ends because there were no more jokes. Jokes have been an alien experiment conducted on Earth and, for a reason I don't remember, at some point they decided to finish it, so people can´t tell new jokes.

Sorry I can´t remember anything more.

Answer (score 32):

I believe this is "Jokester", by Isaac Asimov, first published in December 1956 in Infinity Science Fiction, and collected in *Earth Is Room Enough* (1957) and *Robot Dreams* (1986). It matches the description except for the part saying "the world ends". From the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jokester):

> By computer analysis, the characters in the story investigate the origin of humor ...  The computer eventually tells them that humor is actually a psychological study tool imposed from without by extraterrestrials studying mankind. ... The characters of the story conjecture that figuring this fact out makes it useless as a tool, so the aliens would turn off humour. And suddenly nothing is ever funny again…

Comment: You can read the story [here](https://archive.org/stream/Infinity_v01n06_1956-12_LennyS-cape1736#page/n37/mode/2up).

Comment: A joke is always less funny if you [have to explain that it's a joke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xECUrlnXCqk)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot. I guess I made up the ending :-) I was very young and I guess I thought that a world without humor was the end of the world.